# Did Beruriah add to, "Women are light-headed," to say, "...except Beruriah"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, women, mishna, talmud-bavli, tannaim

I'm seeing a couple of secondary sources which suggest, without citing a primary source, that Beruriah may have supplemented her husband's teaching "Women are light-headed", either orally or in writing, with, "...except Beruriah" or "...but not Beruriah"

Is there any primary source that this is based on?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these secondary sources a secret? Consider including them in your question. From Rashi, who records the infamous legend about Beruriah (AZ 18b), one can suspect that by her mocking of the observation “Women...” she took exception to it.

Comment: See eg this book: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mOtWPalIFA4C&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22except+for+beruriah%22&source=bl&ots=nqOKAshcVA&sig=ACfU3U2OoyUd5gaLcPgI--CiYFftntBV8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-idHd94LjAhVjs3EKHf1kAusQ6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22except%20for%20beruriah%22&f=false

Comment: (I'm familiar with the Rashi, however it doesn't contain the line I'm interested in.)

Comment: That’s the kind of thing you should add in the body of your question - not in a comment. From a quick glance, I don’t see “except for Beruriah” which the author quotes (?) in any of his references sources. (I realize Rashi doesn’t contain it either; only proposing it as indication to the idea that she rejected it as a general rule.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer:

The earliest source I know of which contains the emendation by Beruriah is [R. Avraham Saba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Saba) in his Zeror HaMor ([end of Bihalotecha](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45935&st=&pgnum=235); pub. 1522-23). One can assume either he had a variant reading or he misquoted.

[R. Gedaliah ibn Yachya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedaliah_ibn_Yahya_ben_Joseph) in his Shalshelet HaKabalah ([p. 32a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11643&st=&pgnum=59&hilite=); pub. 1587) also quotes this emendation but the same assumptions are in place including that he may simply have lifted it from the aforementioned source. Incidentally, the famed Christian Hebraist, [Johann Christoph Wagenseil](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Christoph_Wagenseil) (see more about his oeuvre [here](https://seforimblog.com/2019/04/hebrew-printing-in-altdorf/)), quotes this SH in his book on Sotah ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3JFCAAAAcAAJ&dq=%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A5&pg=PP785#v=onepage&q&f=false), p. 500).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!